# Mathematical Entity That Takes a Function and Returns a Function

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, functions

I have been pondering something lately and asked myself whether there is a mathematical construct that takes a function as its parameter and returns another function as its result?

That is, it is a function of a function that produces a function. Is there a term for this? What are some basic facts and where can I learn more about such structures?

Comment: Yes there is, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_transforms , the most common  and used kind of transform is integral transform, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform

Comment: I don't think there's a lot you can say about such functions in general, though there are some interesting special cases.

Comment: There is a term: we call such thing functions!

Comment: Your functional analysis tag is a good one.  Follow that.  Also, these things are everywhere.  If you think a bit you can create your own pretty easily.  For instance, $f \mapsto f(cx)$ is such a transform where $c$ is a fixed constant and $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Don't forget the mapping $f\mapsto f'$.

Comment: In functional analysis we call those guys operators.

Comment: It is a quite common situation where functions of interest comprise points of certain structure (which we often call function space) and then we are interested in maps between such structures. [*Operator theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_theory) is one such example.

Comment: @madphysicist What, in your conception of a function, is a 'normal' function supposed to take as inputs?  In the most common formulations of mathematical foundations, functions typically are defined on a *set* which has *elements*, and usually the elements are *also* sets (although we usually don't think of them as such.) These elements can be numbers, ordered pairs, functions, ... anything that can be formulated as a set.

Answer (score 3):

These are often called *operators*. Some operators take two arguments, called *binary*, like $()\times()$ or $()-()$; others take only one, called *unary*, such as $()^2$.

Some examples of operators or “functions” that take functions $f(x)$ and return functions include

- the derivative $d/dx$
- the derivative’s half-brother the gradient $\nabla$
- the derivative’s twin sister the partial derivative $\partial/\partial x$
- exponentiation $[f(x)]^2$
- multiplication $2\times f(x)$
- addition $f(x)+2$
- function composition $[g\circ f](x)$ if the domain of $g$ and range of $f$ align nicely